# Rotate Image and save to sdcard like whatsapp app in android

Tags: android

I am writing code for rotate image and save to sdcard.

Using Picasso library rotate image and set animation using RotateAnimation.

Following my code

```
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
                Picasso picasso = builder.build();

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mImageFilePath));

    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 90,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
         0.5f);

   rotate.setDuration(800);
   mivProfileImage.startAnimation(rotate);
   picasso.load(uri).rotate(angle).into(mivProfileImage);
```

Problem:

Smooth animation like whatapp app. Is there any library available?

Please help me.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve and what is the issue you are facing? Please make bit more clearer

Comment: @AlokNair In above code image rotate but when image change white screen appear. I want to smooth image rotation like whatsapp.

Comment: Please provide an example screenshot or gif etc of what you want to achieve or where in whatsapp do you see this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Here is agood library : https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations
It animates almost all views.

You will have to apply your on logic to rotate and then save to sd card. Here is an example.

```
Yoyo.with(Techniques.Rotate).duration(800).playOn(YourImageView);
   // this is class for the custom library that I mentioned.
   // This will rotate the imageview in 800 milliseconds. So you want to save the image 
   // to sd card after 800 milli seconds. For this, we need to create a Handler.

Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // save image to sd card after 800 milliseconds.
        }
    }, 800);
```

Comment: Techniques.Rotate not available.

Comment: https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations. check this one. it has rotate animation